# What are the options to filter Enums values from Swagger documentation?

Tags: django, drf-spectacular

I'm using Django with `drf-spectacular` package to generate Swagger documentation. I was wondering is there any better approach to filter out some values from the Enum section inside Schema. Right now I've accomplished this using custom hook `preprocess_schema_enums`

Enums are specified as a field in a models file

hook.py

```py
def preprocess_schema_enums(result, generator, request, public):
  excluded = ['value1', 'value2']
  enums_response = result['components']['schemas']['CustomEnum']['enum']
  filtered = [res for res in enums_resoinse if res not in excluded]
  result['components']['schemas']['CustomEnum']['enum'] = filtered
  return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for custom behavior that deviates from what DRF is actually doing.

There is no amount of switches and settings that could cover each and every user's special requirements. [Post-processing hooks](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#step-6-postprocessing-hooks) were designed exactly for those non-standard use-cases.

So you are using drf-spectacular exactly as intended.